# elasticsearch architecture/development query - ADFS/Security Filtering/SearchUI

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I had a few questions in regards to elasticsearch architecture and associated services and/or products that is not clear to me.
The idea is to setup an elasticsearch instance for searching through file shares, Exchange mailboxes, Sharepoint sites and even Teams conversations if possible.

How would I setup the elasticsearch instance to support the following requirements:

1. Security filtering results from these sources for users
2. Develop on a simple and clean web search page like SearchUI from Elastic themselves.
3. Active Directory or ADFS authentication
4. Use nodejs on a separate server to proxy to elastic, as elastic user management means that users get access to all search results

I can find tutorials and blogs on some of these items, but no comprehensive description of how the architecture would actually work specifically with the SearchUI and proxying of data to ES.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this new product released by Elastic guys using same elastic search framework
https://www.elastic.co/workplace-search
it closley matches your requirement.